# Aplicar o CSS de um filho de elemento A em outro elemento B

Tags: jquery, css

É possível de alguma forma usar regras de CSS aplicadas a `#elemento > .filho` num outro elemento `#dots`?

```
#elemento > .filho{...}
```

No caso eu precisaria que `<div id="dots"></div>` recebesse o estilo da classe `filho`.

---

O que eu eu tenho é `dots` fora da herança, e queria aplicar a ele o estilo `filho`.

```
<div id="elemento">
   <div class="filho"></div>
</div>

<div id="dots"></div>
```

Comment: Você não pode simplesmente fazer: `#elemento > .filho, #dots {...}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso você pode usar o plugin [copyCss](https://github.com/moagrius/copycss), exemplo:

```js
(function($){
 
 $.fn.getStyles = function(only, except) {
  
  // the map to return with requested styles and values as KVP
  var product = {};
  
  // the style object from the DOM element we need to iterate through
  var style;
  
  // recycle the name of the style attribute
  var name;
  
  // if it's a limited list, no need to run through the entire style object
  if (only && only instanceof Array) {
   
   for (var i = 0, l = only.length; i < l; i++) {
    // since we have the name already, just return via built-in .css method
    name = only[i];
    product[name] = this.css(name);
   }
   
  } else {
  
   // prevent from empty selector
   if (this.length) {
    
    // otherwise, we need to get everything
    var dom = this.get(0);
    
    // standards
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
     
     // convenience methods to turn css case ('background-image') to camel ('backgroundImage')
     var pattern = /\-([a-z])/g;
     var uc = function (a, b) {
       return b.toUpperCase();
     };   
     var camelize = function(string){
      return string.replace(pattern, uc);
     };
     
     // make sure we're getting a good reference
     if (style = window.getComputedStyle(dom, null)) {
      var camel, value;
      // opera doesn't give back style.length - use truthy since a 0 length may as well be skipped anyways
      if (style.length) {
       for (var i = 0, l = style.length; i < l; i++) {
        name = style[i];
        camel = camelize(name);
        value = style.getPropertyValue(name);
        product[camel] = value;
       }
      } else {
       // opera
       for (name in style) {
        camel = camelize(name);
        value = style.getPropertyValue(name) || style[name];
        product[camel] = value;
       }
      }
     }
    }
    // IE - first try currentStyle, then normal style object - don't bother with runtimeStyle
    else if (style = dom.currentStyle) {
     for (name in style) {
      product[name] = style[name];
     }
    }
    else if (style = dom.style) {
     for (name in style) {
      if (typeof style[name] != 'function') {
       product[name] = style[name];
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
  
  // remove any styles specified...
  // be careful on blacklist - sometimes vendor-specific values aren't obvious but will be visible...  e.g., excepting 'color' will still let '-webkit-text-fill-color' through, which will in fact color the text
  if (except && except instanceof Array) {
   for (var i = 0, l = except.length; i < l; i++) {
    name = except[i];
    delete product[name];
   }
  }
  
  // one way out so we can process blacklist in one spot
  return product;
 
 };
 
 // sugar - source is the selector, dom element or jQuery instance to copy from - only and except are optional
 $.fn.copyCSS = function(source, only, except) {
  var styles = $(source).getStyles(only, except);
  this.css(styles);
  
  return this;
 };
 
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $("#dots").copyCSS('.filho');
  });
});
```

```css
#elemento > .filho{
  color:red;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elemento">
   <div class="filho">filho</div>
</div>

<div id="dots">Dots</div>
<button type="button">
Aplicar
</button>
```

**OBS: O COLOQUEI O CONTEÚDO DO PLUGIN NA RESPOSTA POIS NÃO ENCONTREI O CDN**

Answer (score 0):

Se sua pergunta estiver certa é só fazer isso que o id dots receberá o estilo da classe filho.

```js
$( "#dots" ).addClass( "outra" );
```

```css
.filho, .outra {
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="elemento">
   <div class="filho">filho</div>
</div>

<div id="dots">dots</div>
```

Comment: Isso eu estou ciente (rs), o problema é que não quero / não posso jogar `.filho` para fora.

Comment: O *css* precisa estar assim: `#elemento > .filho{color:red}`

Comment: Não pode aplicar o mesmo Id duas vezes. Id é único.

Comment: Depois ve se a edição atende.